Fire (as in shooting) in plural
Is it usual to write about “fires” when one means shooting?
I was reading the RUSI report “Preliminary Lessons from Ukraine’s Offensive Operations, 2022–23”, and found that it uses the noun “fire” in a way that I had not seen before. The summary on the web site provides these two examples (there are many more in the full report):

The inability to screen axes of advance from enemy ISR risks sustained
exposure to precision fires, producing an unacceptable rate of
equipment loss.


The combination of sustained enemy observation and long-range fires
meant that once troops were committed to offensive operations, their
ground lines of communication became predictable and targetable,
collapsing tempo.

In both cases, I would have expected “fire” to be uncountable, and hence appear in the singular. What’s going on here?

I suggest using firing: found a flaw in the gun's firing. This looks like either a translation or written by a non-native speaker. What does "collapsing tempo" mean?

Have you checked in a dictionary? CD, ODE and Wiktionary don't license the countification of this sense of 'fire' (as in 'rapid fire'). But as Řídící says, Wikipedia has an article illustrating the usage in the US military. // Words and senses often undergo countification; in spite of disapproval in some quarters, some antiques experts use 'furnitures' (for Louis XIV vs Louis XV, etc).

@WeatherVane "collapsing tempo" --> "causing the tempo of operations to collapse". I don't see any reason to think this passage is not written by a native-speaking human.

It appears that in military usage "fires" can be a singular (and uncountable) noun.

fires — The use of weapon systems or other actions to create specific lethal or nonlethal effects on a target. (JP 3-09)

DOD Dictionary of
Military and Associated Terms (pdf)
Also see Wikipedia.
I suppose it then (in that specific context) resembles words like "news", "measles", "billiards", and "linguistics".

!!! Funny I had never come across this. I suppose this is one of those things that, now that I’m aware of it, will start to appear everywhere.

@TurePålsson I've never come across it, as least in English English. However it could very easily be a "term of art", in the same way that "a good" is used in a legal context even though almost everybody refers to "goods".

"All of the test fires missed their targets." It doesn't sound so outlandish -- and at least this specific combination ("test fires") I have heard in the plural.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas "test shots" or "test rounds" if testing a marksman or a batch of ammunition repectively. "Test volleys" or "test fusillades" if checking a company of riflemen. "Test bombardments" if testing an artillery battery or the competence of a naval vessel. There's really no need for the DoD to invent terms at its whim.
